# How to avoid multiple if else while looping through a cursor fetch?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a cursor which returns the below data.
**Cursor Data:**

| Code | Date | Code_1 | Value_1 | Code_2 | Value_2 | Code_3 | Value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22-Jan-21 | 6 | 50 | 5 | 25 |  |  |
| 2 | 22-Jan-21 | 7 | 35 | 1 | 45 | 6 | 50 |
| 3 | 22-Jan-21 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I need to loop through each row and check for code '6' and get the values until code 6. So, for Row 1, the Value_1 will be retrieved. For Row2, Value_1, Value_2 and Value_3 will be retrieved. And for row 3, nothing will be retrieved. I will use the values retrieved in another calculation.
Can I achieve the same result without having to use multiple if else?

Comment: Is the underlying data in the same format? I.e. is there a table with code_X / value_X columns? Or are you pivoting the data in the cursor to get it into this format? I ask because you don't need to loop through the cursor in PL/SQL to achieve your aims; you should be able to do this in a single SQL statement, but it may be overkill to pivot the data only to unpivot it immediately.

Comment: No unfortunately, this is the raw data that is stored in the database. I have used unpivot to achieve my desired output, but I am still trying to find another solution. I wanted to avoid writing multiple if else because the data set goes all the way upto 18 levels.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the code that built the cursor and the exact output what you are asking for **cannot be determined**. But it may be possible in a single query. With the data as given this can be done. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=73c83ed12edaaaaa1ade002ef2ba5787).

```
select s2.id,  s2.val 
  from ( select id
              , p 
              , code 
              , val
              , lead(code,1) over (partition by id order by id,p) lc1
              , lead(code,2) over (partition by id order by id,p) lc2
           from ( select 1 p, id, code1 code, value1 val from cursor_data union all
                  select 2, id, code2, value2            from cursor_data union all 
                  select 3, id, code3, value3            from cursor_data  
                ) s1
       where s1.code is not null
        order by s1.id, s1.p
        ) s2
 where 6 in (s2.code, s2.lc1, s2.lc2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database is a version that's 11.1 or above, you can use the `UNPIVOT` operator plus an analytic function to do this, e.g.:

```
with your_data as (select 1 id, to_date('22/01/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 6 code_1, 50 value_1, 5 code_2, 25 value_2, null code_3, null value_3 from dual union all
                   select 2 id, to_date('22/01/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 7 code_1, 35 value_1, 1 code_2, 45 value_2, 6 code_3, 50 value_3 from dual union all
                   select 3 id, to_date('22/01/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, null code_1, null value_1, null code_2, null value_2, null code_3, null value_3 from dual union all
                   select 4 id, to_date('22/01/2021', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt, 8 code_1, 10 value_1, 2 code_2, 20 value_2, 5 code_3, 30 value_3 from dual),
     unpivoted as (select id,
                          dt,
                          code_lvl,
                          code,
                          value,
                          min(case when code = 6 then code_lvl end) over (partition by id) first_6_lvl -- might need to add dt into the partition by
                   from   your_data
                   unpivot ((code, value)
                            for code_lvl
                              in ((code_1, value_1) as 1,
                                  (code_2, value_2) as 2,
                                  (code_3, value_3) as 3)))
select id,
       dt,
       code,
       value
from   unpivoted
where  code_lvl <= first_6_lvl
or     first_6_lvl is null -- remove this predicate if no values from row 4 should be returned
order by id, code_lvl;

        ID DT                CODE      VALUE
---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
         1 22/01/2021           6         50
         2 22/01/2021           7         35
         2 22/01/2021           1         45
         2 22/01/2021           6         50
         4 22/01/2021           8         10
         4 22/01/2021           2         20
         4 22/01/2021           5         30
```

I included a 4th row in the sample data to highlight the case where there isn't a code 6 present but there are other values. Depending on your requirements, you may need to include these rows or not. If you don't, it would be more efficient to exclude those rows before you do the unpivot, but that would require a lot of case statements which you say you want to avoid. Alternatively you could just exclude the `or first_6_lvl is null` predicate.

Also, I've assumed that id is the primary key of the data is the id column. If it's the id and dt columns, you need to update the `partition by` clause of the analytic function to include the dt column.